# Problems Installing akka with Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, akka

I have problems 'installing'/configuring akka.io to work with the Scala IDE (based on Eclipse). I followed the tutorial found here (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html) but it didn't work. I get a

not found: type Actor

whenever I try to use an Actor.

I looked all over the internet for a simple solution, but none seem to work. Do you guys have any help? A video would be preferred but not required.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using Akka 2.0 which is quite old. Please checkout the latest here - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that **Akka** is intensively developed, and you're referring to quiet old version `2.0`.

It would be the best if you could start with one of the latest **Akka** version, latest one is `2.3.7`. [2.3.7 Getting Started](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/intro/getting-started.html)

Follow the [akka download](http://akka.io/downloads/) link to grab the latest **Akka** version or event better, one of the **Typesafe Activator** template & tutorial - eg. [Hello Akka!](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-akka?_ga=1.92554333.1722215443.1415226841)

Clone the typesafehub repo `git clone git@github.com:typesafehub/activator-hello-akka.git` and import it as a new project in Scala IDE.

Comment: Hi. I downloaded the new one, but it seems that I am looking at the old instructions. I saw the link you sent, but I had no idea what to do with the github link (since I am using Scala IDE, I assume I need to follow the Eclipse tutorial)

Comment: Clone the typesafehub repo `git clone git@github.com:typesafehub/activator-hello-akka.git` and import it as a new project in Scala IDE.

Comment: It is giving me a problem regarding usage rights. I went to the url and downloaded it as a zip file. No idea what to do now lol.

Comment: If you do not have github account, you need to use `http` `git clone https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-hello-akka.git`

Comment: Thanks fort your answer. I still have no idea what to do with it and how to work this out. I can't import anything to the Scala IDE.